# Proof of $(x/y + y/z + z/x)^2 ≥ 3 · (x/z + y/x + z/y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that for any positive numbers x, y, z the following inequality holds:

$(x/y + y/z + z/x)^2 ≥ 3 · (x/z + y/x + z/y)$

My train of thought was to use Markov's equation and build off of that, but I couldn't make much progress. How could this be proven?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\frac xy=a$, $\frac yz=b$, and $\frac zx=c.$
We have,
$$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\geq 0$$ So,
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+bc+ca$$
So,  $$(a+b+c)^2\geq 3(ab+bc+ac)$$